# Solr: How do I search for a phrase in a field?

Tags: solr

I was reading [the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) and saw this:

> For example, suppose an index contains two fields, title and text,and that text is the default field. If you want to find a document called "The Right Way" which contains the text "don't go this way," you could include ... the following terms in your search query:
>
> ```
> title:"Do it right" AND go
> ```
>
> Since text is the default field, the field indicator is not required; hence the ... query above omits it.
>   The field is only valid for the term that it directly precedes, so the query `title:Do it right` will find only "Do" in the title field. It will find "it" and "right" in the default field (in this case the text field).

This seems strange to me, how would I search for the phrase "Do it right" in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued reading and found the answer in the section titled "Grouping Clauses within a Field".  You can use this:

```
title:("Do it right") AND go
```